# PHP + MSSQL - Value being trimmed to 255 chars when retrieving from DB

Tags: php

The problem is following. When I retrieve data from a specific field via PHP it's being trimmed to 255 characters. Despite the fact it is longer in DB.

```
$query_Result = mssql_query("SELECT comment FROM commments WHERE id = 200");
$query_Data = mssql_fetch_assoc($query_Result);
echo strlen($query_Data['comment']);
```

The story is following. The DB was created before me and the length of 'comment' field was short (maybe even 255 chars). I extended it:

```
ALTER TABLE commments 
ALTER COLUMN comment VARCHAR(1000) NULL
```

Should I have done something else? The value is stored normally - full length. But output is shortened to 255 chars.

Comment: after you changed the column size , have you tried inserting a new row and outputting it to see if this works

Comment: @Satya Yes. Data is stored in database normally - full length. Also tried on another table that was altered - same problem. Really strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you fetch `varchar` fields larger than `255 letters` the result will be cut off at `255 letters`. To prevent this you have to do a `CONVERT(TEXT,data_field)` for this fields in your select clause.
so your code should be essentially

```
$query_Result = mssql_query("SELECT CONVERT(TEXT,comment) FROM commments WHERE id = 200");
$query_Data = mssql_fetch_assoc($query_Result);
echo strlen($query_Data['comment']);
```

Comment: Wow!
That was unexpected. Especially that I read that TEXT will be deprecated  somewhere in the future and saw a suggestion to use VARCHAR instead.

Comment: Thank you                 !  **************

Answer (score 0):

Before Mysql version 5.0.3 Varchar datatype can store 255 character, but from 5.0.3 it can be store 65,535 characters. BUT it has a limitation of maximum row size of 65,535 bytes. It means including all columns it must not be more than 65,535 bytes. Check your Mysql version and use TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, and LONGTEXT to store large texts

Comment: The question is on MS SQL and not MySQL.

Comment: Yep. MS SQL. It has limit of 8000 chars if i'm not mistaken.